# R - filtering Matrix based off True/False vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a data structure that can contain both vectors and matrices. I want to filter it based off of of a true false column. I can't figure out how to filter both of them successfully.

```
result <- structure(list(aba = c(1, 2, 3, 4), beta = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
chi = structure(c(0.438148361863568, 0.889733991585672, 0.0910745360888541, 
0.0512442977633327, 0.812013201415539, 0.717306115897372, 0.995319503592327, 
0.758843480376527, 0.366544214077294, 0.706843026448041, 0.108310810523108, 
0.225777650484815, 0.831163870869204, 0.274351604515687, 0.323493955424055, 
0.351171918679029), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))), .Names = c("aba", "beta", "chi"))

> result
$aba
[1] 1 2 3 4

$beta
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

$chi
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.43814836 0.8120132 0.3665442 0.8311639
[2,] 0.88973399 0.7173061 0.7068430 0.2743516
[3,] 0.09107454 0.9953195 0.1083108 0.3234940
[4,] 0.05124430 0.7588435 0.2257777 0.3511719

tf <- c(T,F,T,T)
```

What I would like to do is something like

```
> lapply(result,function(x) {ifelse(tf,x,NA)})
$aba
[1]  1 NA  3  4

$beta
[1] "a" NA  "c" "d"

$chi
[1] 0.43814836         NA 0.09107454 0.05124430
```

but the $chi matrix structure is lost.

The result I'd expect is

```
ifelse(matrix(tf,ncol=4,nrow=4),result$chi,NA)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.43814836 0.8120132 0.3665442 0.8311639
[2,]         NA        NA        NA        NA
[3,] 0.09107454 0.9953195 0.1083108 0.3234940
[4,] 0.05124430 0.7588435 0.2257777 0.3511719
```

The challenge I'm having a problem solving is how to match the tf vector to the data. It feels like I need to set it using a conditional based on data type, which I'd like to avoid. Thoughts and answers are appreciated.

Comment: I would just write a custom function to apply the TRUE/FALSE vector to your data structure. Then you can apply your function as you need. For the matrix it would be `mat[!tf,  ] <- NA`

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping I wouldn't have to discriminate by type. Converting to data.frame doesn't work either, since it treats the vector as a single row. I may have to do it as a custom function with a data type check.

Comment: How to you expect to do it if it were not based on type?

Comment: You can also possibly check `dim` instead of type.

Comment: Is it not the same data structure every time?

Comment: Replicating the T/F column to match number of columns is how I was hoping to do it. But single column vectors don't have return NULL for dim().

Data structure can be comprised of single column vectors or effectively multi-column vectors. T/F is the same number of rows and provides a filter that way.

Comment: To expand, `lapply(result, function(x) { if (is.null(dim(x))) x[!tf] <- NA else x[!tf, ] <- NA ; x })` should do what you want.

Comment: @AnandaMahto yup - that does exactly what I want. thank you.

Comment: You may also try `Map(function(x,y) {is.na(x) <- !y; x}, result,relist(c(rep(tf,3), tf[row(result$chi)]), result))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how you can avoid either checking the data type or the "dimensions" of the data. As such, I would propose something like:

```
lapply(result, function(x) { 
  if (is.null(dim(x))) x[!tf] <- NA else x[!tf, ] <- NA
  x 
})
# $aba
# [1]  1 NA  3  4
# 
# $beta
# [1] "a" NA  "c" "d"
# 
# $chi
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.43814836 0.8120132 0.3665442 0.8311639
# [2,]         NA        NA        NA        NA
# [3,] 0.09107454 0.9953195 0.1083108 0.3234940
# [4,] 0.05124430 0.7588435 0.2257777 0.3511719
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly simple:

```
 is.na(tf) <- !tf   # convert FALSE to NA
 result$chi[ tf, ]  # and use the default behavior of "[" with NA arg

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.43814836 0.8120132 0.3665442 0.8311639
[2,]         NA        NA        NA        NA
[3,] 0.09107454 0.9953195 0.1083108 0.3234940
[4,] 0.05124430 0.7588435 0.2257777 0.3511719
```

But now I see that you wanted NAs at the corresponging postions of the atomic vectors. Unfortunately "[" with the additional NULL argument would error-out on that type of object.